# unable to set workbook variable to ActiveWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

This is blowing my mind. I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I hope it's just a case of tunnel vision.
I get error message *"Object variable or With block variable not set- 1"*

```
Option Explicit:
Public mWB As Workbook
Public Sub runCSSBatch()
  On Error GoTo Errorcatch

1    mWB = ActiveWorkbook
     Call createTempSheet
     Call findworksheet

  Errorcatch:
     MsgBox Err.Description & "-" & Erl
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     mWB.Sheets("TEMP").Delete
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use "Set mWB = ActiveWorkbook"

Comment: Still getting the same error with Set mWB = ActiveWorkbook. But this time the TEMP sheet does get created and subsequently deleted on error. So something is different. :/

Comment: Whats that 1 in front of mWB?

Comment: it displays the Erl in the error message. Can use it to catch errors.

Comment: I used the test code and didnt encountered any error - Are you sure you are getting the error in this code block and not anywhere else? Try to debug line by line

Comment: Yeeh, I'm doing that now. I've removed the error catching lines. And checking on my other subs. I'm gonna close this cause its clearly not the mWB that's giving the problem. Thanks

Comment: I think it's your rogue 1 that's causing the problem, shouldn't it be `1:  Set mWb = ActiveWorkbook`? Assuming you're using it as a line label for error handling. You also don't need that `:` after `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found many things wrong with my script.

- I did end up using Set in front of ActiveWorkbook (using ThisWorkbook
  was not necessary)
- I believe the comment about using 1: instead of 1 to catch the error
  was valid.
- I am now running the script with quite a few less subs than I was
  before.
- I also had made the mistake of using Cells() inside Range() when one
  excludes the other
- I tried to pass a Worksheet Variable to a Sub (apparently you can't
  do that).
- I'm sure there was more but I can't recall.

I'm going to chalk it up to having a shitty day. :/
As you can see the below code looks nothing like what I had posted initially.

```
Option Explicit:
Public mWB As Workbook
Public Sub runCSSBatch()
   Set mWB = ActiveWorkbook
    mWB.Sheets.Add.Name = "TEMP"
    Dim WSh As Worksheet
    For Each WSh In mWB.Worksheets
        If InStr(WSh.Name, "CSS") = 1 Then
            Call parseRowText(WSh.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub parseRowText(WSName As String)
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim columnCount As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim dataString As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = mWB.Worksheets(WSName)

columnCount = mWB.Sheets(WSName).UsedRange.Columns.Count
rowCount = mWB.Sheets(WSName).UsedRange.Rows.Count

For I = 2 To rowCount
    For B = 1 To columnCount
        dataString = ""
        If mWB.Sheets(WSName).Cells(1, B).Value = "STOP" Then
            dataString = "}"
            Call addToTempSheet(dataString)
            Exit For
        Else
         If B = 1 Then
             dataString = mWB.Sheets(WSName).Cells(I, B).Value & "{"
             Call addToTempSheet(dataString)
         Else
            If dataString & mWB.Sheets(WSName).Cells(I, B).Value = "" Then
            Else
                dataString = mWB.Sheets(WSName).Cells(1, B).Value & ":"
                dataString = dataString & mWB.Sheets(WSName).Cells(I, B).Value & ";"
                Call addToTempSheet(dataString)
            End If
         End If
        End If
    Next B
Next I
End Sub
Private Sub addToTempSheet(dString As String)
    mWB.Sheets("TEMP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = dString
End Sub
```

Comment: You most certainly can pass a worksheet to a Sub!  `Sub Test(MySheet as Worksheet) End` called by `Test(ThisSheet)` (assuming `ThisSheet` has been properly `Set` as a worksheet) will work every time.

Comment: Also, you can use `Cells()` within `Range()`. I have this in some code I'm working on right now `NewSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NewSheet.UsedRange.Row, NewSheet.UsedRange.Column))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ActiveWorkbook, it may be, ThisWorkbook

```
set mwb=thisworkbook
```

Comment: No need to change `ActiveWorkbook`. The key point here is the `Set` keyword as in `Set mWB = ActiveWorkbook`